# invalid literal para int() en base 10 django-filter

Tags: python, django, backend, filtro

soy nuevo en django, quiero filtrar por nombre de usuario.
Entiendo que el campo user es numerico, pero como puedo obtener de el el username.
agradecería mucho su ayuda

utilizo django-filter, django 2.1, python 3.6

model.py

```
class Publication(models.Model):
user =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

filters.py

```
class PublicationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
user = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='exact')
class Meta:
    model = Publication
    fields = ['user']
```

views.py

```
def publication_list(request):
f = PublicationFilter(request.GET, queryset=Publication.objects.all())
return render(request, 'info/filter.html', {'filter':f})
```

html

```
<h2>Lista de sus informes</h2>


        <p class="profile-data">

             <div class="col-md-4 mt-2 mb-3 ">
          <div class="row p-1">
            <div class="col-md-12">


            <form action="" method="get" >
                <b> {{ filter.form.as_p }} </b><br>
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>

              <ul>
               <b>{% for profile in filter.qs %} </b><br>

              <b>{{ profile.nombre }} </b><br>
                <b>{{ profile.user }} </b><br>

               <a href="{% url 'profiles:detail' profile.user %}">Ver perfil</a><br>

              {% endfor %}
```

Comment: para obtener el usuario en tu vista lo harias:  user = request.user......nombre = user.username............idUsuario = user.pk

Comment: Del campo user no vas a obtener el username, necesitas un objeto user, podrias mostrarnos el codigo donde deseas user el username??

Comment: agregue la vista y el html espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes mostrar el error completo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes definir en tu clase `PublicationFilter` dos filtros, uno para el identificador del usuario (`user`) y otro para el nombre del usuario (`user__username`).

Tu clase quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```python
class PublicationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = [
            'user',
            'user__username',
        ]
```

Para utilizar estos filtros, tus requests deberían ser del siguiente estilo:

URL para filtrar por el identificador del usuario

```
http://localhost:8000/publicaciones/?user=1
```

URL para filtrar por el nombre de usuario

```
http://localhost:8000/publicaciones/?user__username=rolandohernandez
```

Comment: muchas gracias hermano!!